# Java Pass an int through Command

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(args[1]));
    String co = sc.next();
    coup = Integer.parseInt(co);
```

I get a FileNotFoundException when I try to pass an int into the second argument in command line. This is only part of the code, a text file is passed as args[0]. However, I can't figure out how to pass a simple integer, only text files.

Comment: You're getting a `FileNotFoundException` which suggests that your program can't find the specified file.  I'd focus on solving that problem first

Comment: I am not sure if I get you right, but can you just use `int coup = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);`?

Comment: You say that there's a text file being read in through `args[0]`, so what are you doing with `args[1]`?

Comment: What is your goal?  Do you want to selectively pass an integer or a filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(args[0]));
    int integerFromCM = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
}
```

You state that a text file is the first argument (args[0]) so assign that in the scanner and when grabbing the integer all you need to do is send args[1] into Integer.parseInt method. You are getting the exception because you are assigning a FileReader object with the file name of the integer passed in.

Comment: I think your solution worked, but I'm not entirely sure yet. I declared a static variable in the class, can I modify that in main by reading in?

int coup = 0; in the class, then 
coup = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); in main?

It's compiling so I think it's good though.

Comment: @user3364161 yes, you can just change the second line of code inside the main method to (coup = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an `int`, but you can parse one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = args[0];
    int i = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    // ...
}
```

If you are getting a `FileNotFoundException`, one easy way to debug it is:

```
File file = new File(filename);
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

and it will be obvious where the problem lies, which is almost always the current directory of the application is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing your code it reads as follows:

1. Create a Scanner to read the file in the first command line argument
2. Get the first integer from that Scanner as a String
3. Parse that String to an int

It is clearly sequenced to require a file from the first argument and that looks like it is intended.

Create a file called number.txt:

```
42
```

NumberPrinter.java:

```
import java.io.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;

public final class NumberPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(args[1]));
        String numberInFile = scanner.next();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numberInFile);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Run as follows:

```
java NumberPrinter number.txt
```

And it will print:

```
42
```

Alternatively if you intend to parse an int directly from the command line parameters try:

```
public final class NumberPrinterDirect {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

NumberOrFilenameAwkward.java:

```
import java.io.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;

public final class NumberOrFilenameAwkward {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int number;
        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException thisIsVeryUgly) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(args[1]));
            String numberInFile = scanner.next();
            number = Integer.parseInt(numberInFile);
        }
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

That is a terrible solution and screams for using a command line parsing library like JewelCLI or commons-cli to solve it cleanly.

Comment: I ended up using 

int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

which worked out. Thanks!